# PostgreSQL: return records that do not fall in X days of a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need the WHERE clause in SQL where I can return records where dateA does not fall within the 15 days before dateB.

Both date fields are columns in my table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE DATE_PART('day', dateA - dateB); <= 15;
```